# Zoom to location on scrollview on iPhone (portrait); not quite right

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit, swift5

In my app the user can add images (a map) and then add pins (small images + attached note) to that image. The map is inside a scrollview. Adding the pins etc works fine, with one small exception: on Iphones in portrait mode (or more precise traitcollection == .compact) I can't get the pin to be and centered and a bit zoomed out. All of this is in a custom splitview controller; notes in the left viewcontroller, map (images + pin) in the right viewcontroller.

On iPad/iPhone in landscape this works just fine by calling:

```
  mapImageScrollView.zoom(to: mapImageLocationPin!.frame, animated: false)
  mapImageScrollView.setZoomScale(1.0, animated: true)
```

with the following result
[image]

On the iPhone in portrait mode the user has to click the double arrow button to navigate to the right viewcontroller with the map. using the same to lines of code as above will result in the map being zoomed in, but *NOT* centered on the pin.
The best I could get it is by using the following code (note that for this to work I have to set the Zoomscale *before* I zoom!)

```
    mapImageScrollView.setZoomScale(0.85, animated: false)
    mapImageScrollView.zoom(to: mapImageLocationPin!.frame, animated: false)
```

This results in centered, but *NOT* zoomed out

[image]
I think it is due to in the second case the right viewcontroller hasn't appeared yet (will do so only after the user taps the double arrow button), but I can't seem to find a better solution ...

Any help appreciated!

The code I use to add the pin to the map:

```
private func addMapImageLocationPin() {
        if let location = annotation?.location {
            //Activate the corresponding Map Image and update picker
            selectedMapImage = location.map
            mapImagePickerView.selectRow(mapImagesController.getRowFor(location.map), inComponent: 0, animated: true)
            
            //Instantiate new Pin with annotation
            mapImageLocationPin = MapImageLocationPin(with: annotation!, andMapImageSize: mapImageView.image!.size)
            mapImageView.addSubview(mapImageLocationPin!)
            
            //Desired height and width
            let desiredWidth: CGFloat = 160
            let desiredHeight: CGFloat = 80
            
            //compensate for scrollView zoomscale, but never bigger than desired width & height!
            let minZoomScale = mapImageScrollView.minimumZoomScale
            let width = min(desiredWidth, desiredWidth / minZoomScale)
            let height = min(desiredHeight, desiredHeight / minZoomScale)
            
            //center the pin image horizontal on location
            let y = location.coordinateY
            let x = location.coordinateX - (width / 2)
            
            //position (frame) the pin
            mapImageLocationPin?.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
            
            //zoom to the pin, different approach for smaller screen sizes
            if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
                mapImageScrollView.setZoomScale(0.85, animated: false)
                mapImageScrollView.zoom(to: mapImageLocationPin!.frame, animated: false)
            } else {
                mapImageScrollView.zoom(to: mapImageLocationPin!.frame, animated: false)
                mapImageScrollView.setZoomScale(1.0, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a little confusing, because you're showing two different locations - why didn't you show North Sweden for both cases, so we could see the difference? Likely, though, you want to execute `.setZoomScale(...)` and `.zoom(...)` either in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` or in `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: Changed the image! Will respond to comment later ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At what point in the layout cycle is `addMapImageLocationPin` being called? If the child view isn't loaded immediately in some instances then you need to ensure that you call the positioning code after the main view has been laid out, such as in viewDidAppear:

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        mapImageScrollView.zoom(to: mapImageLocationPin!.frame, animated: false)
    }
```

Comment: It is being called from a property observer. In case of .compact mode the viewcontroller hasn't appeared yet (though did load). calling the zoom in viewDidAppear seems to do the trick. Will do some more testing and then post an answer based upon this!